# How to add custom shapes to ribbon in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I would like to add my custom shapes to the ribbon in Word 2016.  I've found how to add custom symbols but not shapes, like an arrow.

Comment: Would you please provide more information about your problem? Such as the location where you want to add shapes to. I find that you could try to add your custom shapes to Quick Parts in ribbon. If you need the detail steps, I will write my answer later.

Comment: I am tired of whenever I want to add a shape, like an arrow, start, rectangle to put around text, etc. that I have to recreate it each time I want to add it to my document.   I use a red arrow with certain thickness and arrow head a lot.  I'm tired of how much time it takes each time to make it the way I want it.  I remember reading somewhere that I could make my own shapes and add them to a folder in the ribbon to make it easy to use the same arrow each time, still allowing me to manipulate it for length.